# Check if string contains in *.h files with shell script

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I want to check if string `abcd` contains in 1 of `*.h` files at "/tmp/my folder" directory with shell script

```
if grep -Fxr 'abcd' "/tmp/my folder/*.h"
then
    echo 'yes'
else
    echo 'not'
fi
```

But I got an error /tmp/my folder/*.h No such file or directory

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `*` in quotes. It won't get expanded. Use `"/tmp/my folder/"*.h` (i.e. quote only the *necessary* part) instead.

Aside: This `/tmp/"my folder"/*.h` would also work if you prefer it.

**Alternative to using quotes:**

Use backslash (`\`) escapes, e.g. `/tmp/my\ folder/*.h` -- but I advise against this in general since it can become quite unreadable when dealing with a lot of spaces.

Comment: Even with `"/tmp/my folder/"*.h` I still got error `No such file or directory`

Comment: Are there *any* such files in that directory? What does `ls -l "/tmp/my folder"` give?

Comment: That still not work  `No such file or directory`, even the path didn;t contains space (this path exist)